# Big Commerce Stencil image sizes not working

Tags: bigcommerce

Working on the new big commerce stencil framework and trying to pull in alternative size of images as referenced in https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/global-resources#Stencil-ImageObj-ref

Whilst trying to do this I noticed that image sizes are not altered anywhere on the site and remain at original uploaded sizes.

Does anyone know how to fix this or if I need to change code somehow?

Here is an example bit of code

```
{{#if post.thumbnail}}
        <figure class="blog-thumbnail">
            <a href="{{post.url}}">
                <img src="{{getImage post.thumbnail 'gallery_size'}}" alt="{{post.thumbnail.alt}}">
            </a>
        </figure>
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change part of your config.json file to the old format.

At some point they switched the config.json from this style:

```
[OLD FORMAT THAT STILL WORKS]
"settings": {
  ...
  "logo-position": "center",
  "_images": {
    "logo_size": {
      "width": 750,
      "height": 300
    },
    ...
    "zoom_size": {
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 1280
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

to this style:

```
[NEW FORMAT THAT DOESN'T WORK]
"settings": {
  ...
  "logo-position": "center",
  "logo_size": "250x100",
  "brand_size": "190x250",
  "gallery_size": "300x300",
  "productgallery_size": "500x659",
  "product_size": "500x659",
  "productthumb_size": "100x100",
  "thumb_size": "100x100",
  "zoom_size": "1280x1280",
  "blog_size": "190x250",
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this answer will help you.. :)

I have tried following to change the size of the images. And it worked.

If required, you can apply margin attribute in style.

```
<img src="{{getImage thumbnail 'gallery_size'}}" style ="width:200px; height:200px;" alt="{{thumbnail.alt}}">
```